# Show the following including number of divisors d(n)

Tags: number-theory

1. - I know how to show that $(d ∗ \mu)(n) = 1$ for all n ≥ 1.But..
     I have two solutions.
     Firstly... result is trivial, because $d = 1 ∗ 1$ 
     Secondly We know that both sides are multiplicative. Thus it suffices to check it for primes powers.But how do i write this mathematically because I could not simplify in order to get 1.
2. - How do I show d(n) is odd if and only if n is square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let us verify that $d * \mu(n) =1$ for all $n$ by direct computation. As you said, this funcion is multiplicative, so it is completely determined by its values at prime powers $p^k$. By definition $$d * \mu(n) = \sum_{b|n} d(b) \mu\left(\frac{n}{b}\right)$$ so that $$d * \mu(p^k) = \sum_{b|p^k} d(b) \mu\left(\frac{p^k}{b}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^k d(p^i)\mu(p^{k-i})$$ since the divisors of $p^k$ are precisely $1, p, p^2\ldots, p^k$ . In particular, notice that $d(p^k)=k+1$.

But recall that the Möbius function vanishes on every number divisible by the square of a prime. Then all summands are zero except for $d(p^k)\mu(1)=d(p^k)=k+1$ and $d(p^{k-1})\mu(p)=k\mu(p)=-k$. Therefore $$d * \mu(p^k)=(k+1)-k=1.$$

As for your second approach, I believe it is perfectly fine and justified by the Möbius inversion formula, which you seem to be aware of.

2. You need an explicit formula for $d(n)$. Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ be the prime factorization of $n$. Then we have $$d(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(\alpha_i+1).$$

Accepting this formula as true, if $n$ is a perfect square, then all the $\alpha_i$ must be even, i.e. each factor $\alpha_i+1$ in the product above is odd. Thus $d(n)$ itself is odd.

Note: to prove the formula, you can just observe that $d$ is multiplicative (you are already assuming this when taking its convolution in part 1), and that its value at a prime power $p^k$ is $d(p^k)=k+1$ as I said before.